# Empty value for Date type in Swift

Tags: swift, date, types, declaration

I'm very new to swift.

How to set empty value for `Date` type in Swift to be used in declarations?

**Like:**

`var string: String = ""` for `String` type

`var integer: Int = 0` for `Int` type.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not empty value, but default value. So, one of the most used default values for `Date` is for example `Date()`

Comment: More context might be helpful. Do you want to set an *initial value* or an *empty value*? The latter would be the Optional `nil` in Swift.

Comment: Not all types accept empty initializers. `0` for `Int` has a meaning in addition/substraction. `1` would be the right empty initial value for an `Int` in multiplcation/division. Have you contemplated using optionals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) :

> A Date value encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any
>   particular calendrical system or time zone. Date values represent a
>   time interval relative to an absolute reference date.

In other terms, a date is nothing but a `TimeInterval`, A.K.A a `Double` representing the number of seconds since a reference date. Then, an empty initializer for `Date` would be the one that returns a date 0 seconds away from that reference date. It all comes down to choosing the reference date :

- Now : `let date1 = Date()`
- Jan 1, 1970 at 12:00 AM : `let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)`
- Jan 1, 2001 at 12:00 AM : `let date3 = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)`

You can choose a certain date as a reference if it makes sense to you. Examples: `Date.distantPast`, `Date.distantFuture`, ...

Now, if you want a variable to have a certain type, but no value, then use [optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) and set their values to `nil`:

```
var date4: Date? = nil
```

Later on, when you want to actually use the variable, just set it to a non-nil value:

```
date4 = Date(timeInterval: -3600, since: Date())
```

To use the actual value, you'll have to unwrap it using optional binding or the likes of it.